# Flutter Disabled TextField Not Show ErrorText

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with flutter disabled text field, its work with alert which provide some choices when clicked.

I validate the value using stream like code below in my case:

```
final validateGender =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (text, sink) {
    if (text.isEmpty ||
        text.toLowerCase() != 'male' ||
        text.toLowerCase() != 'female') {
      sink.addError('* Not choose yet');
    } else {
      sink.add(text);
    }
  });
```

and i make a textfield that can show errorText:

```
StreamBuilder<String>(
  stream: stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return TextField(
      enabled: enable,
      autofocus: isAutoFocus ?? false,
      onTap: onTap,
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      errorText: snapshot.error,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        ),
      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.gray, width: 1.0),
        ),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
        ),
      filled: true,
      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      hintText: hintText,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

it supposed to be show "* Not choose yet" below of the text field, but it show red border only. the result below:

[image]

my stream using rxdart, i think i don't need to put it here,

Answer (score 8):

Set the errorStyle property of the TextFormField's input decoration property to use any color you want for the error (for both enabled and disabled fields):

```
TextFormField(
  ...
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    ...
    errorStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
    ),
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: Theme.of(context).errorColor is deprecated. Use Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error

Answer (score 0):

Have your choose anything? Please check what's your **snapshot.error** is printing,

Your border is red because you added error text field, please handle it, After validation then add error text, either null.

Answer (score -1):

If it's disabled, it's pretty unlikely that the form validator will run the validation for that field.  (Put a print() trace in to find out.)  Do you really want Flutter wasting time on disabled form elements? :)